# Unable to compile v3.5 .NET Projects in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have finished converting a wsp solution to a vs 2010 solution.  But while trying to compile one of the projects, I got the following compilation error:

```
The type "System.Func<T,TResult> exists in both 'c:\program files (x86)\Reference assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll' and 'c:\windows\microsoft.NET\Framework64\4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll'
```

I have removed the System.Core.dll, and made sure the target framework in the project is set to v3.5.  However the error still appears.

I have tried the numerous solutions proposed in stackoverflow threads.  None have worked so far.

I'm trying to use the v.3.5 framework to compile.  I'm running out of ideas... are there any other Microsoft references that quietly uses the v4.0 to compile?  This is causing a lot of grief...

Thanks.

Comment: If you create a *new* project, does that have the same issues? I've built .NET 3.5 projects in VS2010 for ages...

Answer (score 0):

Modify your project file.

```
<Reference Include="System.Core">
    <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Tried... to no avail.  And you are missing a "v" in front of 3.5.